# Real sequences, proof with banach space theory

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

Can someone help me with this?

Let $(x_n)$ be a real sequence, and suppose that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i y_i$ does converge for every real sequence $(y_n)$ such that $lim_{n \to \infty} y_n =0$.
Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i|< \infty$

I've found this exercise in a banach space chapter, but a purely calculus proof would be good aswell.

Comment: Non-Conditional convergence implies absolute convergence, perhaps?

Comment: First time i've heard about this definition. I'll look up somewhere

Comment: May I know this exercise is taken from which book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equivalently, RTP that if $\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}|x_n|=\infty$ then there exists a sequence $(y_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converging to $0$ such that $\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} x_ny_n$ does not converge.

Notation: $sgn(x)=|x|/x$ if $x\ne 0$ and $sgn(0)=0.$ (Latin: signum.)

If $\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}|x_n|=\infty $ then there exists a strictly increasing sequence $(M_j)_{j\in \Bbb N}$ of natural numbers with $M_1=1$ and such that for every $j$  we have $$\sum_{n=M_j}^{M_{j+1}-1}|a_n|\geq 1.$$

For $M_j\leq n < M_{j+1}$ let $y_n=j^{-1}sgn (x_n).$ Then $\lim_{n\to \infty}y_n=0$. Since $x_ny_n\geq 0$ for all $n,$ we have  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_ny_n=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=M_j}^{M_{j+1}-1}x_ny_n=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}j^{-1}\sum_{n=M_j}^{M_{j+1}-1}|x_n|\geq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(1/j)=\infty.$$

Comment: Let l$_0$ be the Banach space of real sequences $(y_n)_n$  that converge to $0,$ with $\|(y_n)_n\|_0=\sup_n |y_n|.$  Then $l_0^*=l_1$, That is why this is  in a Banach-space chapter.

Comment: Yes, your construction is beautifully crafted. I was struggling to prove with Baire's Category theorem, that is, I wish to derive contradiction by assuming $\sup_{\|(y_{n})\|\leq 1}\left|\displaystyle\sum_{n}x_{n}y_{n}\right|=\infty$ so then I can have a uniform bound for that, then the duality of $c_{0}$ and $l^{1}$ comes into play, so do you know how to argue with Baire's Category theorem?

Comment: I can't think of way to involve Baire.

Comment: I agree, that was a real good costruction. Thanks for the help and nice work!